# How to position the TextView from code?

Tags: android

Is it possible to place the `TextView` in some position which I calculate within my code.
I have the x and y position with me (which i get after the calculation) and I just want to place the `TextView` in that position.

How can i implement it?
Please Help.

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, I could place `TextView`s along a curved line.
I just used Absolute layouts. I think that was the only possible method.

Answer (score 3):

The below code may help you:

```
TextView widget = new TextView(screenContext);
widget.setText("Label"+widgetCount);
widget.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(width,height, calculatedX,calculatedY));
```

This works only when you are using absolute layout, I assume, you are using it.